# Two variable limit problem with piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a function from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(t)=f(-t)$ and for $t \geq 0$: $$f(t)= \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } t=0\\ \frac{(2n+1)t-1}{n(n+1)} & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{n+1} \leq t < \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$$

Prove that $$\lim_{(x,x') \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x')-f(x)}{x'-x}=0$$

I can't find a nice way to solve this. Approximating $f(x)$ with writing $\frac{1}{n+1}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $x$ simplifies the expression quite a bit, but if I do that then in the denominator I'm dividing by zero for some $(x,x')$ pairs. Is there any simple and clean way to go about this?